# Extracting polynomials from a cubic spline function

Tags: graphics, interpolation, splines

I have this set of three data points and I want the natural cubic spline functions for them:

```
  dat = {{-.0247500, .5}, {.3349375, -.25}, {1.101000, 0}};
```

I tried:

```
  f = SplineFit[dat, Cubic]
```

Using another approach and code, I get the two cubic functions (I am trying to verify the correctness) as:

$$\begin{align*}
-0.481347 + 0.753113 x - 0.0338047 x^2 - 0.455282 x^3\\
-0.506486 + 0.978281 x - 0.706073 x^2 + 0.213767 x^3
\end{align*}$$

Is there any way to see these results and the intermediate results to derive the two cubics using *Mathematica*? (I tried looking at documentation and could not make sense of it.)

Comment: Are you saying there is no MMA approach to getting the spline points and we have to resort to an interpolating function?

Comment: This is a very good question and the answer I believe is no, there is (frustratingly) no *direct* way to elicit the actual functional form (coefficients) produced by spline fit (or many similar functions)

Answer (score 8):

I've finally decided to write a "modern" re-implementation of the old `SplineFit[]` routine from `` NumericalMath`SplineFit` ``. In the course of writing it, I was struck by how crude it actually is compared to some of the interpolation methods I've presented in past answers. Thus, *except for the purpose of reproducing the output of `SplineFit[]` from old calculations*, I **do not recommend** its use, as there are now better methods.

```
splinefit[dat_?MatrixQ] :=
          Module[{n = Length[dat], del = Differences[dat]},
                 del = LinearSolve[SparseArray[
                       {Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, 
                        Band[{1, 1}] -> ArrayPad[ConstantArray[4, n - 2], 1, 2], 
                        Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}], 
                       ListCorrelate[{{3}, {3}}, del, {-{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {0}]];
                 BSplineFunction[#1, SplineDegree -> 3, SplineKnots -> #2] & @@
                 {Join[{dat[[1]]},
                       Riffle[Most[dat] + Most[del]/3, Rest[dat] - Rest[del]/3],
                       {dat[[-1]]}],
                  ArrayPad[Riffle[#, #] &[Range[0, n - 1]], 2, "Fixed"]}]
```

For instance, here is [the example from the old docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/StandardPackages/NumericalMath/SplineFit.html):

```
sf = splinefit[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {-1, 3}, {0, 1}, {3, 0}}];

sf[1.4]
   {0.2651428571428573, 2.7017142857142855}

ParametricPlot[sf[t], {t, 0, 4}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: old SplineFit[] example]

---

Starting with

```
dat = {{-.0247500, .5}, {.3349375, -.25}, {1.101000, 0}};
```

use the new `splinefit[]` on it:

```
f = splinefit[dat];
```

Unfortunately, as it stands, `BSplineFunction[]` objects are immune to exposure from `PiecewiseExpand[]`. The routine could certainly be modified so that the results are entirely in terms of `BSplineBasis[]`. Instead, I'll demonstrate some undocumented functionality for extracting knots and control points from `BSplineFunction[]` objects, which we can then use with `BSplineBasis[]`:

```
n = First[f["Degree"]];
knots = First[f["Knots"]];
cpts = f["ControlPoints"];
```

(A complete(?) list of supported methods can be obtained from `f["Methods"]`.)

The explicit form of the piecewise polynomial functions can then be recovered like so:

```
fun[x_] = FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[
                       Table[BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, j - 1, x],
                             {j, Length[cpts]}].cpts]];
```

I've omitted the result, but you can compare it yourself with the ones obtained by Ray in his answer.

Comment: What exactly do you refer to by "there are now better methods"?

Comment: @murray: the "natural" spline implemented in the old package is not usually used anymore in applications; one now uses either "not-a-knot" or polynomial fits to get the end conditions needed to produce a unique spline. In addition, the old package uses a uniform parametrization, which is often not the best choice. One can do e.g. centripetal or chord length parametrization to get a better-looking curve. So yes, the old implementation is a little bit long in the tooth.

Answer (score 6):

```
f1[x_] = a1 + b1*x + c1*x^2 + d1*x^3;
f2[x_] = a2 + b2*x + c2*x^2 + d2*x^3;
s = Solve[{f1 @ dat[[1,1]] == dat[[1,2]],
           f1 @ dat[[2,1]] == dat[[2,2]],
           f2 @ dat[[2,1]] == dat[[2,2]],
           f2 @ dat[[3,1]] == dat[[3,2]],
           f1' @ dat[[2,1]] == f2' @ dat[[2,1]],
           f1'' @ dat[[2,1]] == f2'' @ dat[[2,1]],
           f1'' @ dat[[1,1]] == 0,
           f2'' @ dat[[3,1]] == 0},
          {a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2}]
(* {{a1 -> 0.438903, b1 -> -2.46492, c1 -> 0.221098, d1 -> 2.97775,  
     a2 -> 0.603324, b2 -> -3.93762, c2 -> 4.61804, d2 -> -1.39813}} *)
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{f1[x], x ≤ dat[[2, 1]]}}, f2[x]] /. s;

Plot[f[x], {x, dat[[1, 1]], dat[[3, 1]]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> None, 
     Prolog -> {PointSize[.02], Point /@ dat}]
```

[image: plot]

EDIT, Re the comment by @george2079 -- `SplineFit` uses the same algebra that I used, but instead of fitting `y` to `x`, which is what I did, it fits `x` and `y` separately to their (zero-based) indices, `Range[0, Length @ dat - 1]`.

```
( spline = SplineFit[dat, Cubic] ) // InputForm
```

gives the following, which I have formatted, rounded, and annotated:

```
SplineFunction[Cubic,
{0., 2.},  (* index range *)
{{-0.02475,    0.5 },  (* x[[1]], y[[1]] *)  
 { 0.3349375, -0.25},  (* x[[2]], y[[2]] *)
 { 1.101,      0   }}, (* x[[3]], y[[3]] *)
{{{-0.02475, 0.25809375, 0., 0.10159375},   (* coeffs for fitting x[[{1,2}]] *)
  { 0.5,    -1.,         0., 0.25      }},  (*   "     "     "    y[[{1,2}]] *)
 {{ 0.3349375, 0.562875, 0.30478125, -0.10159375}, (*  "     "    x[[{2,3}]] *)
  {-0.25,     -0.25,     0.75,       -0.25      }} (*  "     "    y[[{2,3}]] *) }]
```

There are two splines implicit in the above:

```
X[u_] = Piecewise[{{-.02475 + .25809375 u + .10159375 u^3, 0 ≤ u ≤ 1},
  {.3349375 + .562875 (u-1) + .30478125 (u-1)^2 - .10159375 (u-1)^3, 1 < u ≤ 2}}];

Y[u_] = Piecewise[{{.5 - u + .25 u^3, 0 ≤ u ≤ 1},
  {-.25 - .25 (u-1) + .75 (u-1)^2 - .25 (u-1)^3, 1 < u ≤ 2}}];
```

Note that `u` is shifted so that the argument of the polynomial is always in $[0,1]$.

In the following, changing `spline[u]` to `{X[u], Y[u]}` does not change the plot:

```
ParametricPlot[spline[u],{u, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, Axes -> None,  
               AspectRatio -> Automatic, Prolog -> {PointSize[.02],Point /@ dat}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: note this is a different result from SplineFit. Likely SplineFit uses some different end conditions..

Comment: InputForm! .. +2 for that if I could..