# How to find a length of a curve constructed using Spline?

Tags: geometry, splines

By fitting the data using spline, I have created a curve.

```
sp = SplineFit[data1, Cubic]
```

I am trying to divide this curve into small segments of equal length. To do so, I am trying to calculate the length of the curve using:

```
NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + sp'[z]^2], {z, 0, 34}]
```

I get:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand \!\(\*SqrtBox[
RowBox[{\"1\", \"+\", SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{SuperscriptBox[TemplateBox[{\"\\\"SplineFunction[\\\"\",\"Cubic\",\"\\\", \\\"\",RowBox[{\"{\", RowBox[{\"0.`\", \",\", \"34.`\"}], \"}\"}],\"\\\", \\\"\",\"\\\"<>\\\"\",\"\\\"]\\\"\"},
\"RowDefault\"], \"\[Prime]\",
MultilineFunction->None], \"[\", \"z\", \"]\"}], \"2\"]}]]\) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,34}}."
```

I am new to *Mathematica* and I really do not understand how splines work. I am trying to use the technique mentioned in [How do I split up a curve into chords of equal length?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8970/) to divide the curve into equal segments.

Comment: What version do you have? `SplineFit` seems to be somewhat deprecated.  We now have `Interpolation`, `BezierFunction`, `BSplineFunction` -- maybe others I don't recall.  The `SplineFunction` does not seem to be symbolically differentiable.

Comment: I have Mathematica 9 as well as 10. I tried to Interpolate but I couldn't do so because I had to interpolate both x and y coordinates.

Comment: Like this? `xydata = Table[{t Cos[t], t Sin[t]}, {t, 0., 10}]; pf = Interpolation[ MapThread[{{#1}, #2} &, {Rescale@Range@Length@xydata, xydata}], Method -> "Spline"]; ParametricPlot[pf[t], {t, 0, 1}]`. Note the data for `Interpolation` should be in the form `Table[{{t}, {x, y}}, {t,...}]` -- note the braces carefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the somewhat outdated Splines package:

```
Needs["Splines`"]

f = SplineFit[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 2}, {0, 1}}, Cubic];

ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `SplineFunction` cannot be differentiated symbolically:

```
f'[0]
(*  (SplineFunction[Cubic, {0.,3.}, <>]^\[Prime])[0]  *)
```

`NDSolve` can construct a numerical derivative (apparently):

```
{arclength} = 
  NDSolve[{y[t] == f[t], s'[t] == Sqrt[y'[t].y'[t]], x'[t] == 1, 
    y[0] == f[0], x[0] == 0, s[0] == 0}, s, {t, 0, 3}];

s[3] /. arclength
(*  6.59702  *)

Plot[s[t] /. arclength, {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are better ways, I think, if you have version 7 or higher.  But I love how robust `NDSolve` is.  (Probably, if you have a version below 7, it won't be robust enough to do the above.  I cannot check that myself.)

**Addendum**

If generating evenly spaced points is the goal, then Alexey Popkov's answer to "[How to get a uniformly distributed list of points from a B-spline function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54841/how-to-get-a-uniformly-distributed-list-of-points-from-a-b-spline-function/64345#64345)" is the easiest way:

```
plot = ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 3}, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> {15}, 
 MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can get the points (not the parameter) this way:

```
Cases[Normal @ plot, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity]
(*
  {{0.395124, -0.117757}, {0.985196, 1.74711}, {0.648418, 1.50936},
   {0.321879, 1.25766}, {0.794663, -0.219251}, {1.34214, 1.9529},
   {1.96322, -0.0415362}, {1.73477, 2.07018}, {1.61147, -0.246155},
   {2.17169, 0.311035}, {2.09348, 1.90693}, {2.25271, 1.52986},
   {1.20225, -0.278889}, {2.27279, 0.709978}, {2.29956, 1.12093}}
*)
```

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't understand your solution. How did you come up with that differential equation?

Comment: @psimeson The arclength $s$ is the integral of $\sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2}\,dx$ or of $\sqrt{(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2}\,dt$. The first case is for a curve of the form of the graph of $y=f(z)$; the second is for a parametrized curve $x=x(t),\,y=y(t)$, which is your case. In your question you seemed to use the first form, but the second form is the correct one. Hence the `s'[t] == Sqrt[y'[t].y'[t]]` equation. The rest defines `y` = `f` = your Spline parametrization, and the dummy ODE system `x'[t] == 1, x[0] = 0` is a standard trick to force `NDSolve` to integrate the system (it's the only ODE of the DAE)...

Comment: ...(DAE = "Differential Algebraic Equation").  One could use `s'[t] = Norm[s'[t]]` instead of `s'[t] == Sqrt[y'[t].y'[t]]` and it works (at first I thought it wouldn't).  While `NDSolve` is integrating `x'[t] = 1`, it will also be setting `y[t] == f[t]` and numerically integrating the arclength `s` via the equation `s'[t] == Sqrt[y'[t].y'[t]]`.

Comment: You have used MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}. In this case does "ArcLength" denote {arclength}? If so then why have you capitalized "a" and "L"?

Comment: @psimeson I capitalized it thus because *Mathematica* is a programming language and you have to use the spelling of the keywords as they are defined in the language.  (`SemanticInterpretation` is changing this, to a little extent.)

Comment: I am very new to Mathematica. I am trying to learn Mathematica by doing this project. So, I hope you won't get offended by my very foolish questions. Why did you use {} for arclength, while doing NDSolve? As after as i know {} are used for lists and NDSolve spits out InterpolatingFunction as an output. Other than Mathematica's documentation, could recommend me any text or notes that would help me understand Mathematica?

Comment: @psimeson `sol = NDSolve[..]` gives `{{s -> InterpolatingFunction[..]}}`.  Then `s[0.5] /. sol` gives `{value}` in a list. This is because `sol` is treated as a list of solutions `{sol1}`. To get just `value` we need to get rid of an extra set of braces. One way is to use `s[0.5] /. First[sol]`; similarly, one can use `sol = First[NDSolve[..]]`. Another way is to use a list assignment as I did. Note `{x, y} = {1, 2}` is the same as `x = 1; y = 2`. Similarly `{arclength} = NDSolve[..]` is the same as `{arclength} = {{s -> ..}}`, which is the same as `arclength = {s ->..}`.

Comment: @psimeson See the "Introduction" part of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/259#259) for links to introductory materials.

Comment: @psimeson You're welcome.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the correlation between unit tangent vectors (http://www.uni-leipzig.de/~pwm/web/?section=introduction&page=polymers). To calculate unit tangent vector, I need to take the derivative of the curve at that point. Since it's cubic spline, I can't do so. I am trying to approximate it by (http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/~cathale/lects/bio322-phybio1/2013bio322/lab2-mtPersistLen.pdf) . Do you know of any better way to do it?

Comment: Is there a way to extract angles between each segments?

Comment: @psimeson You can use `ArcTan[x, y]` to get angles.  If `path` is an ordered list of points, then `Differences[ArcTan @@@ Differences@path]`.  If the points are not ordered, then `FindCurvePath` can help.

Comment: As suggested by you I can get coordinates using `coord= Cases[Normal@plot, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity]` , So to get angles I can use ArcTan[coord] right? But it's not going to work because of the structure of coord.

Comment: This is what I did `Table[ArcTan[coord[[i]][[1]], coord[[i]][[2]]], {i, 1, Length[coord]}]`

Comment: @psimeson Don't you need to take the difference of consecutive points to get the vectors? And then you want the angle of the vectors?  And then the difference of the angles, to give the angle between the vectors?  At least that's how it seemed to me.

Comment: That's correct. After drawing a simple vector diagram I see why `Differences[ArcTan @@@ Differences@path]` makes sense.

Comment: What is 'ArcLength` in `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}`? It's not defined in mathematica and the way you have defined it's `arclength` not `ArcLength`.

Comment: @psimeson Please see the reference linked in my answer.

Comment: In my case those coordinates are not ordered: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86382/confusion-with-splinefit-angle-calculation

Comment: @psimeson Please see this comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83181/how-to-find-a-length-of-a-curve-constructed-using-spline/83183#comment232901_83183

Comment: `FindCurvePath` seems to give sensible distribution but the polymer that I get out of it is not sensible, which is discussed here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86382/confusion-with-splinefit-angle-calculation/86391#86391

Answer (score 6):

If you do have version 10, another possibility is to use the new geometric computation functionality:

```
ArcLength@DiscretizeGraphics@BSplineCurve@data1
```

The above give the total length. To find the length of the segment of the spline function `sp` between times `t1` and `t2`, you could extend the same approach like so:

```
length[{t1_, t2_}] := ArcLength@DiscretizeGraphics@ParametricPlot[sp[t], {t, t1, t2}]
```

Note that this is **not** a good solution if you want to use the `length` function to find roots, as `ParametricPlot` will throw out errors if a non-numeric limit is supplied. Perhaps in the future, though, *Mathematica* will offer more options for working with geometric regions.

---

I also found a few things out while investigating Michael E2's excellent answer:

1. `BSplineFunctions` *can* be symbolically differentiated, but what is produced is a little different than normal:

   ```
   f = BSplineFunction[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}];

   df = D[f[t], t] (* -> BSplineFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>][t] *)
   ```

   that is, it is already acting on `t`. We can plot it

   ```
   ParametricPlot[df, {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1]
   ```

   [image: df]

   and find arc length with `NIntegrate`:

   ```
   s[tf_] := NIntegrate[Norm@df, {t, 0, tf}];

   s[1] (* -> 5.30301 *)
   ```

   (Note that the equation for the arc length is $ds(t) = \sqrt{(dx/dt)^2 + (dy/dt)^2} dt $, hence the use of `Norm@df`.)
2. To find the points that split a `BSplineFunction` into equal parts, we can use `NDSolve`, which is robust enough to handle the curve directly:

   ```
   findcuts[sf_, n_] := Module[
     {ti, tf, length, sol, times},
     {{ti, tf}} = sf["Domain"];
     length = NIntegrate[Norm@D[sf[t], t], {t, ti, tf}];
     {{sol}, {times}} = Reap@NDSolve[
       {r'[t] == Sqrt[sf'[t].sf'[t]],
        r[0] == 0,
        WhenEvent[Evaluate[Mod[r[t], length/n]], Sow[t]]},
       r, {t, ti, tf}];
     sf@# & /@ Drop[times, -1]];

   Show[ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}], ListPlot[findcuts[f, 7], PlotStyle -> Orange]]
   ```

   [image: f]

   I heartily agree with Michael E2 about the versatility of `NDSolve`!

Comment: I do have access to Mathematica 10. Thanks Virgil, the first command worked. It's nice that Bspline uses cubic spline. Is there a similar powerful way to divide this curve into segments of equal length?

Comment: @psimeson, not that I know of (but many people here know more than me). Probably your best bet is to go with the method outlined in your linked question.

Comment: One more question: Using ArcLength@DiscretizeGraphics@BSplineCurve@data1 I got the length to be 55.3209 and using length[{0,34}] = 56.0843 (This the contour length of the curve that I got using Image J). I don't know why these two are different.

Comment: @psimeson, I get the same kind of difference. I think is stems from the difference between the way `DiscretizeGraphics` treats  `BSplineCurve` and `BSplineFunction`. It seems that `BSplineCurve`, which is a graphics primitive, can only be approximated, so the quality of the discretization cannot be improved by passing options like `MaxCellMeasure` or `MeshQualityGoal` to `DiscretizeGraphics`. The parametric plot of the `BSplineFunction` can, however, be improved, so that should give a better arc length measure.

Comment: @psimeson, actually, all nonlinear primitives can only be approximated by `DiscretizeGraphics`, so the parametric plot of the `BSplineFunction` cannot be improved either. However, the discretization seems to go by plot points, so it will take advantage of `ParametricPlot`'s adaptive sampling and should be a closer fit in areas of higher curvature.

Comment: @psimeson, also, while this is a nice clean method, I don't think it can be used with numeric functions like `NDSolve` and `FindRoot`, so in the end it may not be what you want (too bad there isn't a geometric way to divide the curve). I think that Michael E2's answer is probably the best if you want to find the times dividing your curve into equal lengths.

Answer (score 2):

Something easy to do, not very efficient though.

```
dz = .0000001;
arc[z_]:=NIntegrate[Norm[(sp[z + dz] - sp[z])/dz], {z, 0, 34}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In [this previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97281), I gave a function that reproduces the functionality of the old `` NumericalMath`SplineFit`​ `` package, and outputs a function in `BSplineFunction[]` format. Unlike the older function, it plays nice with differentiation, which allows us to use it with `NIntegrate[]` to find the overall arclength:

```
sf = splinefit[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 2}, {0, 1}}];
NIntegrate[Norm[sf'[t]], {t, 0, 3}]
   6.597018140608958
```

Of course, if you want an arclength function, you could use `NDSolve[]` in the same manner as Michael did for his answer:

```
s = NDSolveValue[{sp'[t] == Norm[sf'[t]], sp[0] == 0}, sp, {t, 0, 3}]
```