# Why are these methods giving me different results? (Trying to test SplineFit)

Tags: geometry, splines

I am creating a polymer(where each monomer is of equal length) using this method:

```
angles = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.2], 40];
a1 = 1;
anglePath1[angles_, a_] := FoldList[# + a {Cos@#2, Sin@#2} &, {0, 0}, Accumulate@angles]
p1 = anglePath1[angles, a1];
```

Then, I use `SplineFit`

```
Needs["Splines`"];
spt = SplineFit[p1, Cubic];
lt = spt[[2, -1]];
```

Then, I break the polymer into monomer of equal length. To do so, I calculate the arc length of the polymer:

```
dz = .0000001;
arc = NIntegrate[Norm[(spt[z + dz] - spt[z])/dz], {z, 0, lt}]

mesh = Solve [arc/a1 == div];
meshf = Round[div /. mesh];
```

After this I extract co-ordinates:

```
plot = ParametricPlot[spt[t], {t, 0, lt}, 
         MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> {meshf[[1]]}, 
         MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.01], Red}]

coord = Cases[Normal@plot, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity];
```

So, now I calculate distance between each points:

```
(*distance calculated using initially created co-ordinates*)
Norm /@ Differences@p1

(*distance calculated using co-ordinates grabbed from spline fitted curve*)
Norm /@ Differences@coord
```

These two distances are different and I don't understand why.

The method calculating arc length and grabbing co-ordinates are from @MichaelE2 answer from this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83181/how-to-find-a-length-of-a-curve-constructed-using-spline):

Comment: Your code doesn't run as shown. For instance, your first variable `angle` should probably be called `angles`, as you show in use further down when you define `p1`. Further, the `SplineFit` doesn't work because `i` is not defined. Please past back the code you post in a clean *mathematica* session and make the necessary modifications until it runs.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks. It was written to analyze multiple polymers.I forgot to clean those stuffs in this code. Now, it should run fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your points aren't in order. Change:

```
coord = Cases[Normal@plot, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity]
```

by

```
coord = Sort@Cases[Normal@plot, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity]
```

Then you'll get

```
(Norm /@ Differences@p1)[[1 ;; 5]]
(Norm /@ Differences@coord)[[1 ;; 5]]

(*
{1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}
{0.976258, 0.97659, 0.975463, 0.976125, 0.976947}
*)
```

Comment: Note : This is still doesn't give ordered/sorted coordinates. As discussed here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86382/confusion-with-splinefit-angle-calculation