# Confusion with SplineFit (Angle calculation)

Tags: distributions, geometry, splines

This question is a continuation to [this other one][1]

I am creating polymers (where each monomer is of equal length) using this method:

```
num = 50;
angles = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.2], 80], {i, 1, num}];
a1 = 1;
anglePath1[angles_, a_] := FoldList[# + a {Cos@#2, Sin@#2} &, {0, 0}, Accumulate@angles]
p1 = Table[anglePath1[angles[[i]], a1], {i, 1, num}];
```

Then, I use SplineFit

```
Needs["Splines`"];
spt = Table[SplineFit[p1[[i]], Cubic], {i, num}];
lt = Table[spt[[i]][[2, -1]], {i, num}];
```

Then, I break the polymer into monomers of equal length. To do so, I calculate the arc length of the polymer:

```
dz = .0000001;
arc = Table[
  NIntegrate[
   Norm[(spt[[i]][z + dz] - spt[[i]][z])/dz], {z, 0, lt[[i]]}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 12], {i, num}]

mesh = Table [Solve [arc[[i]]/a1 == div], {i, 1, Length[arc]}];
meshf = Flatten[Round[div /. mesh]]
```

After this I extract co-ordinates:

```
plot = Table[ParametricPlot[spt[[i]][t], {t, 0, lt[[i]]}, 
       MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> {meshf[[i]]}, 
       MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.01], Red}], {i, num}];

coord = Table[
   Sort@Cases[Normal@plot[[i]], Point[p_] :> p, Infinity], {i, num}];
```

Now I am trying to calculate angles:

**1. Using Coordinates p1**

```
vecp = Table[Differences@p1[[i]], {i, 1, num}];
vecp2 = Table[Partition[vecp[[i]], 2, 1], {i, 1, num}];
angp = Table[VectorAngle @@@ vecp2[[i]], {i, 1, num}];
angp2 = Flatten[angp];
```

**2.Using Coordinates coord**

```
vecc = Table[Differences@coord[[i]], {i, 1, num}];
vecc2 = Table[Partition[vecc[[i]], 2, 1], {i, 1, num}];
angc = Table[VectorAngle @@@ vecc2[[i]], {i, 1, num}];
angc2 = Flatten[angc];
```

Both of these angles should have Normal Distribution (similar to the distribution of `angles`):

```
Histogram[Flatten[angles], {0.1}]
```

But I don't get similar distribution.
[1]: [Why are these methods giving me different results? (Trying to test SplineFit)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86290/why-are-these-methods-giving-me-different-results-trying-to-test-splinefit/86333#86333)

Comment: @belisarius I checked using `ListPlot[coord[[1]]]` and I got plots that looked good. Using `ListPlot` it was looking good before sorting and I guess it was so because it was just showing me the coordinates. When I used, `ListPlot` with lines option it wasn't good at all. Is there a sequential way of extracting the co-ordinates? Even though the `p1` is in sequential the angles calculated from it does not have the same distribution as `angles`

Comment: But please try to explain why you are doing all that.You are starting with points at equal distances, then you're fitting them to a Spline and then you try to recover those (more or less) same points. Why??

Comment: @belisarius The reason, I am doing this is to see if `SplineFit` is introducing some artifact of not. By testing `SplineFit` on artificially created polymer ( of which I know almost everything  about (e.g. arc length, persistence length)), I can be sure about robustness of `SplineFit` and then I can use it on some experimental data. When I tried to use `SplineFit` on my experimental data I was getting some weird answer.

Comment: @belisarius I am getting this `Part::partd: "Part specification cc[[{9,3,4,5,46,75,30,6,35,67,50,39,17,36,68,64,12,57,29,47,18,13}]] is longer than depth of object."`  when I tried `coord = Table[ cc[[First@ FindCurvePath[ cc = Cases[Normal@plot[[i]], Point[p_] :> p, Infinity]]]] , {i, num}];`

Answer (score 5):

The following is (I believe) a better implementation for at least two reasons. First, it doesn't use the old `Splines` package, but `Interpolation[..., Method -> "Spline"]` instead. Second, if uses an algorithmic arc length parametrization to get the equispaced points instead of relying on the mesh generated by `ParametricPlot` which is nice for displaying but not designed for extracting the points' coordinates from the plot.

I also modified the way you are measuring the inter-monomer angles, for the better, I think.

```
ClearAll[setMonomerPoints, getInterpolatingCurve, 
         getEquispacedPointsOnCurve, arcLenReparametrization];

setMonomerPoints[numberOfMonomers_, monomerLength_, angleSigma_] := 
 Module[{angles, anglePath},
  anglePath[angles_, a_] := FoldList[#+ a {Cos@#2,Sin@#2} &, {0,0}, Accumulate@angles];
  angles = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, angleSigma], numberOfMonomers];
  anglePath[angles, monomerLength]
  ]

getInterpolatingCurve[pts_, interpOrder_] := Module[{prepList},
  prepList = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, pts];
  Interpolation[prepList, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> interpOrder]
  ]

getEquispacedPointsOnCurve[fun_InterpolatingFunction, numberOfpoints_] :=
 Module[{cLen, dom = First@fun["Domain"], z, arcLenReparametrization, 
        eqNewCoords, eqParmRange},

  arcLenReparametrization[f_, len_] := arcLenReparametrization[f, len] =
    Module[{t, s}, NDSolveValue[{t'[s] == 1/Norm[f'[t[s]]], t[0] == dom[[1]]}, 
                                 t, {s, 0, len}]];

  (* Calculate total curve arc length *)
  cLen = NIntegrate[Norm[fun'[z]], Evaluate@{z, Sequence @@ dom}, MaxRecursion -> 12];
  (* generate numberOfpoints+1 points along the interval {0, cLen} *)
  eqParmRange = Rescale[Range[0, 1, 1/numberOfpoints], {0, 1}, {0, cLen}];
  (* Calculate the value of the function's parameter in those points *)
  eqNewCoords = arcLenReparametrization[fun, cLen][eqParmRange];
  (* calculate the position for the equispced points *)
  fun /@ eqNewCoords]
```

A test drive:

```
SeedRandom[42];
nMonomers = 80;
ss = setMonomerPoints[nMonomers, 1, .2];
f = getInterpolatingCurve[ss, 3];
eqsp = getEquispacedPointsOnCurve[f, nMonomers];
ListPlot[{ss, eqsp}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
         PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[.01], Green}, {PointSize[.005], Black}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The points look the same because the curve is smooth but it "follows" the segmented line quite well. But despite the look, they aren't the same:

```
ListPlot[EuclideanDistance @@@ Transpose[{ss, eqsp}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please note that if you change in the code above

```
eqsp = getEquispacedPointsOnCurve[f, nMonomers];
```

by

```
eqsp = getEquispacedPointsOnCurve[f, nMonomers / 2];
```

You'll get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's generate and check the angle's statistic you're worried about. We will use the `Cross` product instead of `VectorAngle` to preserve the signs:

```
SeedRandom[42];
nMonomers = 80;
sigma = .2;
p1 = Table[setMonomerPoints[nMonomers, 1, sigma], {100}];
p2 = getEquispacedPointsOnCurve[#, nMonomers] & /@ (getInterpolatingCurve[#, 3] & /@ p1);
vecc2 = Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ Differences /@ p2;
vecc3 = vecc2 /. {x : _?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, 0};
angc = ArcSin[Flatten[Map[Cross @@ #/Times @@ Norm /@ # &, vecc3, {2}][[All, All, 3]]]];
GraphicsRow[{Histogram[angc, {.01}], 
             ProbabilityPlot[angc, NormalDistribution[0, sigma]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
So everything looks fine enough :)

---

Finally a warning note: If you have a good fit for the interpolating curve but you can't estimate well the number of monomers, the statistics may go astray. Just look;

```
SeedRandom[42];
nMonomers = 80;
sigma = .2;
p1 = Table[setMonomerPoints[nMonomers, 1, sigma], {100}];
(* Note the "2" in the line below *)
p2 = getEquispacedPointsOnCurve[#, nMonomers/2] & /@ (getInterpolatingCurve[#, 3]&/@ p1);
vecc2 = Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ Differences /@ p2;
vecc3 = vecc2 /. {x : _?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, 0};
angc = ArcSin[Flatten[Map[Cross @@ #/Times @@ Norm /@ # &, vecc3, {2}][[All, All, 3]]]];
GraphicsRow[{Histogram[angc, {.01}], 
             ProbabilityPlot[angc, NormalDistribution[0, sigma]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for taking time to address this problem. I am new to mathematica so I try to stick with `Table`. However, it's good learn the way you prettified the code. I tried to plot `coord` and `p1` , and found that they look different. Could you please explain how `coord = Module[{cc = Cases[Normal@#, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity]},  cc[[First@FindCurvePath[cc]]]] & /@ plot;` works? I have never used module before.

Comment: Ok. I tired to plot and check polymer and some the polymers look way different than the original polymer.

Comment: If they are different then how can they have same statistics.  I am looking at this : `Graphics@Line@p1[[6]]` and `Graphics@Line@coord[[6]]`. I get that we are looking at an ensemble when we are taking about the statistics but the way the polymers are transformed I am having hard time to accept it. Did you find a link to that nice alternative in v10?

Comment: As mentioned earlier I am new to Mathematica, so I was suggested to use `SplineFit` at first and I got stuck with it. I did try `Interpolation` for a fit but without `Spline` option, which wasn't that helpful.

Comment: @psimeson Ok, Let me try an alternative. I'm working on it.

Comment: ok. let me know

Comment: There you have it

Comment: I more or less (mathematically) understand what you did here but I am not used to mathematica implementation with all these pure functions and shortcut. I am trying to figure out how you implemented it. It would be nice to have some comments along the code to know what you were thinking.

Comment: What is reason for using `preplist` for `Interpolation` ? Could you please explain `getEquispacedPointsOnCurve` function? What does `arcLenReparametrization[f_, len_] := arcLenReparametrization[f, len]` mean?

Comment: @psimeson `preplist` is a trick to force `Interpolation[ ]` to return a vector valued function of a scalar parameter. Interpolation when used with preplist  returns a function `f:R -> R^2`

Comment: The other thing with `arcLenReparametrization` is called [**memoization**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean/2645#2645)

Comment: why do we need "scalar" parameter? I didn't understand `NDSolveValue[{t'[s] == 1/Norm[f'[t[s]]], t[0] == dom[[1]]}, t, {s, 0, 
  len}]` `cLen = NIntegrate[Norm[fun'[z]], Evaluate@{z, Sequence @@ dom}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 12]` and `eqParmRange = 
 Rescale[Range[0, 1, 1/numberOfpoints], {0, 1}, {0, cLen}]` . Basically, I don't understand how you extracted equispaced coordinates.

Comment: @psimeson I added some comments in the `getEquispacedPointsOnCurve`. Hope that helps you. As for the arc length reparametrization I am using a standard coding already discussed several times in this site. For example [**here**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55322/193)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25076/discussion-between-belisarius-and-psimeson).