# How to reproduce old SplineFit function?

Tags: fitting, splines

Prior to version 8, Mathematica included a [`SplineFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Splines/ref/SplineFit.html) function that could be used, for example, in the form:

```
dat = RandomReal[{}, {5,2}];     
SplineFit[dat, Cubic]
```

(Prior to version 7, `SplineFit` was part of the separate standard add-on package Splines.)

How can one reproduce the result with the current version of Mathematica, now that `SplineFit` is gone?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97281)?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive: No I had not seen that; this should help. It would still be very useful if I could somehow reproduce the behavior of `SplineFit` in my situation (https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1636443) using currently built-in, high-level functions.

Comment: If it's for display/plotting rather than evaluation at a point, the function in my answer can be modified so that it directly produces a `BSplineCurve[]`; I suppose that's what you want?

Comment: `SplineFit` is *not* gone. I can still run ``Needs["Splines`"]; dat = RandomReal[{}, {5, 2}]; SplineFit[dat, Cubic]`` and I get a functioning `SplineFunction` object. Why re-invent the wheel then?

Comment: @MarcoB: could be dangerous, for future stability, to rely on the `Splines` package, which is somewhat hidden in the current version. the docs, at page `Spines/SplineFit` says, "As of Version 7.9, some of the functionality of the Splines Package is now built into the Wolfram Language kernel". But it doesn't say just what substitutes for `SplineFit`.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive: In the post you cite, you say, "there are now better methods" than your re-implementation of `SplineFit`. Exactly what are those methods? All I need is an implementation of `SplineFit[{pts}, Cubic`. I don't directly see how to use `Interpolation` (with option `Method -> "Spline"`). And I don't see how to exploit the several currently built-in spline-related functions, as they merely use the given points as control points rather than actually pass the (piecewise) spline through those points.

Comment: "All I need is an implementation of `SplineFit[{pts}, Cubic]`" - and that's what's in that answer. I only added the caveat that it isn't the best thing to use anymore. (See e.g. [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11738) for one of the "better methods".)

Answer (score 2):

It appears you can reparametrize a [`BezierFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierFunction.html):

```
len = 20;
SeedRandom[111];
rand = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {len+1, 3}];

Needs["Splines`"]
fit = SplineFit[rand, Bezier];

bf = BezierFunction[rand];

Table[Chop[fit[t] - bf[t/len]], {t, 0, len, .01}] // MinMax
```

> ```
> {0, 0}
> ```

Comment: That covers the `Bezier` case; some additional work is needed for `CompositeBezier`. `Cubic` is covered by my previous answer, as noted in the comments.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive: But my object is to try to avoid using the `Splines` package version of `SplineFit`. (Or was that a type and you meant to use your `splineFit` in this answer.)

Comment: @murray, this isn't my answer; my answer in the other thread doesn't use the package.