# Different results using spline interpolation in Wolfram and MATLAB

Tags: interpolation, splines, matlab

I use the same data for interpolation in *Mathematica* and MATLAB, but the result is different.

```
x={-1.00,-0.96,-0.65,0.10,0.40,1.00};
y={-1.0000,-0.1512,0.3860,0.4802,0.8838,1.0000};
Interpolation[{x,y}//Transpose,Method->"Spline"][-0.3]
```

result: `-0.87332`

```
x=[-1.00,-0.96,-0.65,0.10,0.40,1.00];
y=[-1.0000,-0.1512,0.3860,0.4802,0.8838,1.0000];
splinetx(x,y,-0.3)
```

result: `-0.1957`

I tried different `InterpolationOrder` but still different.

Is the  `"Spline"` same as `splinetx`?

If not, is there a function in Wolfram like `splinetx`?

---

The `splinetx` function is available [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/37976/versions/7/contents/splinetx.m) or [here](https://users.wpi.edu/~sweekes/MA3457/splinetx.m).

MATLAB also has a built-in [`spline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) function which gives identical results to `splinetx`.

---

This is a comparison of the results given by *Mathematica* and MATLAB:

[image: comparison]

Comment: What methods does `splinetx` use? The short answer to your first question is no. And the short answer to your second question is yes. The methods used in MATLAB or gnu octave and other similar programs can be realized with WL functions.

Comment: The source code of `splinetx` can be found here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/37976/versions/7/previews/splinetx.m/index.html

Comment: MATLAB also has a built-in `spline` function which also gives -0.1957. I think this is a good question and it is worth trying to understand the source of the differences.

Comment: Since we have the source code for the MATLAB version, it could no doubt be reproduced in Mathematica with some effort. It is not particularly interesting. But can we reproduce Mathematica's version? I think it is important to fully understand and to be able to reproduce what Mathematica does ... I don't see enough in the documentation to be able to easily do this. The difference must be coming from the conditions on the endpoints.

Comment: In any case, this is an incorrect problem, no matter what algorithm we use.

Comment: @Szabolcs It’s definitely the conditions on the end points. They use the “not-a-knot” condition on the end points...I can’t recall if I implemented this in my Numerical Methods course last semester or not. I’ll check & see what I come up with! I was pretty stubborn and wanted to use WL in Mathematica instead of learning to use anything else, and I’m not sure if I implement it before the course ended up breaking me hah!

Comment: @AlexTrounev What do you mean by "incorrect problem"?

Comment: @Szabolcs You want to draw a curve through 6 points. There is no one solution.

Comment: @AlexTrounev That much is clear. What I am looking for is not the "correct" solution (as there isn't any single one) but a precise understanding of what `Interpolation` does here (I guess the question is what is assumed for the derivatives at the boundaries)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the  `"Spline"` same as `splinetx`?

- No.

> If not, is there a function in *Wolfram* like `splinetx`?

- No.

---

That was a bit negative. However, it is not too difficult to apply the formulae in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62454) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3137658) to derive a routine that generates not-a-knot cubic splines (as was astutely observed by CA Trevillian and others in the comments.)

Of course, one can use `SparseArray[]` + `LinearSolve[]` to solve the underlying tridiagonal system, so I'll do that in the function below:

```
notAKnotSpline[pts_?MatrixQ] := Module[{dy, h, p1, p2, sl, s1, s2, tr},
    h = Differences[pts[[All, 1]]]; dy = Differences[pts[[All, 2]]]/h;
    s1 = Total[Take[h, 2]]; s2 = Total[Take[h, -2]];
    p1 = ({3, 2}.Take[h, 2] h[[2]] dy[[1]] + h[[1]]^2 dy[[2]])/s1;
    p2 = (h[[-1]]^2 dy[[-2]] + {2, 3}.Take[h, -2] h[[-2]] dy[[-1]])/s2;
    tr = SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> Append[Rest[h], s2], 
                      Band[{1, 1}] -> Join[{h[[2]]}, ListCorrelate[{2, 2}, h], {h[[-2]]}], 
                      Band[{1, 2}] -> Prepend[Most[h], s1]}];
    sl = LinearSolve[tr, Join[{p1}, 
                              3 Total[Partition[dy, 2, 1]
                                      Reverse[Partition[h, 2, 1], 2], {2}],
                              {p2}]];
    Interpolation[MapThread[{{#1[[1]]}, #1[[2]], #2} &, {pts, sl}], 
                  InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> "Hermite"]]
```

Try it out on the points in the OP:

```
pts = {{-1., -1.}, {-0.96, -0.1512}, {-0.65, 0.386},
       {0.1, 0.4802}, {0.4, 0.8838}, {1., 1.}};
spl = notAKnotSpline[pts];

spl[-0.3]
   -0.195695

Plot[spl[x], {x, -1, 1},
     Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[6], ColorData[97, 4]], Point[pts]}]
```

[image: points with not-a-knot spline interpolant]

Demonstrate the $C^2$ property of the cubic spline:

```
Plot[{spl[x], spl'[x], spl''[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-10, 30}]
```

[image: not-a-knot spline with first two derivatives]

---

Szabolcs's desire to reproduce the results of `Method -> "Spline"` is a bit more difficult, because the exact formulae being used are not disclosed publicly. That being said, [I was able to reverse-engineer and reproduce it some time ago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84240), so go look at that answer if you want more details.

Comment: (I actually have a more general spline interpolation function than this, but the code is in a hard disk many kilometers away, so releasing that will have to wait.)

Comment: Thanks！It's very helpful. I've read your answers and write a natural cubic spline function. It seems that the `Method -> "Spline"` in  `Interpolation` is not a natural cubic spline. So what the conditions are actually used for it? Why _Mathematica_ use  an uncommon method?

Comment: I wrote a natural spline routine in [another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214299/), and the formulae used by `Method -> "Spline"` are in the answer I linked to in the last paragraph. Why these choices were made, I cannot say.