# Understanding Interpolation with Cubic Splines

Tags: interpolation, splines

My ultimate question: given data, what function is `Interpolation` with `Method->"Spline"` creating?

I recall from my graduate Numerical Analysis class years ago that piecewise spline interpolating functions had certain nice properties. The classic construction of natural splines can be found on Wolfram MathWorld [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html).

A colleague gave me some chemistry-related data and wanted to fit it with a smooth interpolating function. I was frustrated with how seemingly difficult this was to do with *Mathematica*. Googling "Mathematica spline interpolation" likely takes one to the MathWorld page above, or to obsolete functions like `SplineFit`, described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Splines/ref/SplineFit.html).

I found `Interpolation`, but for some reason the default settings don't produce a smooth curve. (Isn't that a natural desire?) The MathWorld page references `BSplineCurve`, which doesn't naturally compute an interpolating function, though the dedicated reader will find an example of interpolation if they read to "Applications/Interpolation" which requires the use of additional, unexplained code to compute knots.

After I computed my own natural cubic spline of the data, I found that `Interpolation` has a `Method` option where "Possible settings include "Spline" for spline interpolation...".

All three methods of computing a smooth interpolating "spline" produce different results. With the sample data set `pts={{1,2},{2,4},{3,1},{4,3},{5,5},{6,2}}`, the blue curve is produced with `Interpolation[pts, Method->"Spline", InterpolationOrder->3]`, the black curve is produced using `BSplineCurve` and the documentation's Interpolation example, and the red, dashed curve is the classic natural spline per the MathWorld algorithm.

[image: interpolating splines of the same data]

Again, my primary question is: what function is `Interpolation` with `Method->Spline` computing? A secondary question would be "Why doesn't *Mathematica* have a built-in natural spline creating function?

Edit:
The BSplineCurve code, taken from the documentation:

```
dist = Accumulate[Table[EuclideanDistance[pts[[i]], pts[[i+1]]], {i, Length[pts]-1}]];    
param = N[Prepend[dist/Last[dist], 0]];
knots = {0, 0, 0, 0,1/3, 2/3, 1, 1, 1, 1};
m = Table[BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, j - 1, param[[i]]], {i, 6}, {j, 6}];
ctrlpts = LinearSolve[m, pts];
Graphics[BSplineCurve[ctrlpts]]
```

Also, my cubic spline code isn't concise and isn't worth sharing, but I can confirm it produces the same function as `ResourceFunction["CubicSplineInterpolation"][pts,"Natural"]`, as suggested in the comment.

Comment: Please include the data and the code you used that generated the non-smooth result you mention. Also please include the code you used to generate the "classic natural spline" from your sample data.

Comment: You might be interested in the resource function [`CubicSplineInterpolation`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CubicSplineInterpolation/). It has options for natural, clamped, not-a-knot flavors of cubic splines, and it returns an [`InterpolatingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html)

Comment: I've updated with the BSplineCurve code. Also, the `CubicSplineInterpolation` `ResourceFunction` does what I want. I stumbled on it as I was researching this question, though didn't try it. I don't understand the role of these resource functions; they seem like user-contributed functions, correct? They don't seem like a regular part of the Wolfram Language.

Comment: OP, the purpose of the (mostly) user contributed resource functions are that they add non-traditional functionality to the WL. They are well-vetted by WRI, and serve to meet (seemingly) niche use cases such as these. You might also be interested in any of the other interpolation resource functions like [`AkimaSpline`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AkimaSpline/) or [`AkimaInterpolation`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AkimaInterpolation/).

Comment: I don't know if it's documented, but it produces a not-a-knot spline, like Matlab's `csapi(x, y)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can confirm that the `Interpolation` produces a "not-a-knot" spline when using the "Spline" method by comparing the results of different spline end condition implementations from the [`CubicSplineInterpolation` resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CubicSplineInterpolation/). That function generates cubic splines in natural, clamped, not-a-knot, and other flavors.

```
pts = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}, {4, 3}, {5, 5}, {6, 2}};

builtin = Interpolation[pts, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 3];

resfun = ResourceFunction["CubicSplineInterpolation"][pts, #] &;
notaknot = resfun["NotAKnot"];

Plot[
  Evaluate@Through[{builtin, notaknot}[x]],
  {x, 1, 6},
  PlotLegends -> {"built in", "not-a-knot"}
]
```

[image: plots of built-in and not-a-knot interpolation results overlap perfectly]

The plot above shows that the two results are identical, confirming that the built-in produces a not-a-knot cubic spline.

---

To attempt to answer your second point, "not-a-knot" splines seem to be generally preferred over natural splines nowadays, [as mentioned in comments by @JM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35405/extracting-polynomials-from-a-cubic-spline-function/97281#comment504561_97281). This is reflected in the default choices in e.g. [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html), Mathematica (as shown above), and SciPy's [`scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html) which all default to not-a-knot end conditions for their cubic splines.

For comparison, here are other kinds of cubic splines obtained from the same data:

```
natural = resfun["Natural"];
clamped = resfun["Clamped"];

Plot[
  Evaluate@Through[{builtin, notaknot, natural, clamped}[x]],
  {x, 1, 6},
  PlotLegends -> {"built in", "not-a-knot", "natural", "clamped"}
]
```

[image: plot with the four kinds of splines]

---

The question [How to make a natural cubic spline](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/214299/27951) was answered by @JM with code for `naturalSpline`. This was his second, most recent (2020) implementation of natural cubic splines that I could find on this site. He had also contributed an older version (see [this answer from 2015](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97281/27951)).

Comment: A very nice answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you!

Comment: Agree with @MichaelE2; well done, @MarcoB. I'll have to read up on not-a-knot splines to see why they are preferable over other splines.

Comment: @Greg, mostly, this is because when you approximate a smooth function with cubic splines, the not-a-knot condition is generally fourth-order accurate, while the natural condition is only second-order accurate. (Numerical analysis textbooks that discuss splines will have a more precise statement of this.)