# Geogebra spline command in Mathematica

Tags: interpolation, splines

[Spline(pts, order, Weight Function)](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Spline_Command)

> Creates a spline with given order through all points. The weight function says what should be the difference of t values for point $P_i$ and $P_{(i+1)}$ given their difference $P_{(i+1)} - P_i = (x, y)$. To get the spline you expect from "function" algorithm you should use `abs(x) + 0*y`, to get the GeoGebra's default spline you can use `sqrt(x^2+y^2)`.

Its implementation may be [here](https://github.com/geogebra/geogebra/blob/master/common/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/interpolation/SplineInterpolator.java).

Is there a corresponding function in *Mathematica*? I checked the documentation of the `Interpolation` and `BSplineFunction`,
I don't know how to set the weight function to reproduce the result. Let's say I have points `pts` like this, I generated the corresponding curve in *Geogebra*, which I converted into *Mathematica* code.

```
pts={{0,0},{1,1},{2,-1},{3,2},{4,1}};

cond={t<0.17,t<0.44,t<0.83,True};

val={{-11.52t^3+6.16t,-125.22t^3+9.52t},
{2.14t^3-7.05t^2+7.37t-0.07,159.41t^3-146.79t^2+34.75t-1.45},
{12.42t^3-20.72t^2+13.44t-0.97,-108.17t^3+209.4t^2-123.29t+21.93},
{-19.62t^3+58.87t^2-52.48t+17.23,115.04t^3-345.13t^2+335.92t-104.83}};

f[t_]=Piecewise[Transpose[{val,cond}]]

Show[ParametricPlot[Join[{f[t]},val]//Evaluate,{t,0,1},PlotStyle->{Black,Dashed,Dashed,Dashed,Dashed}],
Graphics[{PointSize[Large],Point[pts]}],PlotRange->{{0,5},{-2,3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: If you find out what kind of boundary constraints Geogebra uses, then you could try to use the weighting scheme shown in the answer below with the [`CubicSplineInterpolation` resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CubicSplineInterpolation/). See also [Understanding Interpolation with Cubic Splines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/268285/27951).

Comment: @Marco's idea is a good one. I don't have time to write something detailed, but: `pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}}; tp = N[ResourceFunction["LeeInterpolatingNodes"][pts, 1]]; ResourceFunction["InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise"][ResourceFunction["CubicSplineInterpolation"][Transpose[{tp, #}], "Natural"], t] & /@ Transpose[pts] // Expand` and compare with what Geogebra does.

Answer (score 7):

Your link documents the default weight function but it doesn't say which kind of boundary constraints are used to obtain a unique spline.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}};

(* Geogebra default weight *)
ts = Prepend[Accumulate[N[Normalize[Norm /@ Differences[pts], Total]]], 0]
(* {0, 0.17190381, 0.44370759, 0.82809619, 1.} *)
```

To get a spline with these parameter values for the points you can use `Interpolation`, but the result still differs because the boundary is handled differently:

```
ParametricPlot[Interpolation[Thread[{ts, pts}], Method -> "Spline"][x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: What is called the "default weight" here is more properly known as "chord-length parametrization". The `parametrizeCurve[]` function from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26898) with the second argument set to `1` will do this.